# Пунктуация при уточняющем обороте

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

> А после, со спокойной душой, они плюхнулись на мягкие диваны.

Выделяется ли "со спокойной душой"?

Answer (score 5):

**А после, со спокойной душой, они плюхнулись на мягкие диваны.**

Оборот обособляется, и это связано со структурой предложения (М.Г. здесь совершенно прав).

Только оборот **не имеет значение уточнения, это дополнительное сообщение,** которое автору важно выделить путем обособления.

Именно поэтому выбрана **соответствующая структура:** в начале предложения следуют **два неоднородных обстоятельства**, из которых **сложно (по смыслу)**  составить единую фразу простого предложения: *А после со спокойной душой // они плюхнулись на мягкие диваны.* **Вариант с обособлением более корректен и выразителен.**

Сравнить: **А после /они со спокойной душой //плюхнулись на мягкие диваны.**
Это предложение не требует обособления. Сочетание "они со спокойной душой" вполне корректно для первой части предложения, **после** ― детерминант, который относится ко всему предложению (читается с небольшой паузой).

**Проверки** же вида "а именно" к этому предложению отношения не имеют.

Comment: >> _...которое автору важно выделить путем обособления..._ Откуда вы знаете, что автору важно, а что нет? Может быть, автор просто страдает синдромом повышенной грамотности -- знаете, что это такое? Это когда всюду хочется ставить запятые, особенно в тех местах, где есть (можно сделать) паузы при чтении.

Comment: Взаимодействие трех принципов русской пунктуации осуществляется по следующей схеме: семантика (что важно автору) - структура (ее выбирает автор в соответствии с семантикой) - знаки препинания, которые следуют из заданной автором структуры. Эта схема работает во всех случаях, в том числе в приведенном предложении. Если автор ВЫБРАЛ такую структуру, значит, для него ВАЖНО выделить обстоятельственный оборот.

Comment: А может, проще открыть справочник?

Comment: Вы задали уточняющий вопрос, и я вам (и в первую очередь,  всем остальным участникам форума) ответила достаточно подробно. Но комментарии не предназначены для обсуждения вопросов посторонних или неясно заданных. (Читайте правила пользования сайтом).

Comment: Никаких вопросов я не задавал, тем более уточняющих. А по теме: никаких запятых здесь не нужно, если автор не Максим Горький или другая какая знаменитость. Вот им можно почти что угодно.

Comment: Jasmin, Я учел Ваше замечание и внес поправки в свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Не всегда "со спокойной душой" выделяется, но в данном случае структура и интонационный строй предложения располагают его выделить, только здесь, как заметила Jasmin, не уточнение, а дополнительное сообщение, которое нужно  выделить путем обособления. Лучше всего запятыми.

Answer (score 1):

Не выделяется - совершенно нет причин считать его уточнением. А после, а именно со спокойной душой? Так сказать нельзя.